# Formatting data after collection from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

In the following way I can format the data when I assign to the object:

```
def cost=( w )
    super w.gsub( ",", "." ).gsub( /[^0-9\.]/, "" ).to_f
end
```

Is there a simple way to do it the other way?
I mean that when I get the price from the database automatically formats the data like in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. In your view just use [number_with_delimeter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_delimiter), e.g.:

```
<%= number_with_delimiter @record.cost %>
```

This assumes you have your Rails locale set to the appropriate local for the formatting you want to use. Otherwise you can force a local, e.g.:

```
<%= number_with_delimiter @record.cost, :locale => :fr %>
```

By the way, you *could* do this in your model by overriding `cost`, e.g.:

```
def cost
  some_formatting_method self[:cost]
end
```

...but that would be breaking with MVC principles. It's best, as I said, to do this in your view, with the built-in helpers.

Comment: Thx for your reply. Method with the price I used only as an example. If I wanted to do other operations on the number or string then the helper "number_with_delimeter" is not useful. I'll try to test your second idea with overriding in the model.

Comment: Debian: Rails makes it very easy to write your own helpers. Give it a shot.